# Is 'kaaskop' considered a racial slur in the Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, local-customs

My father would sometimes call the Dutch cheddar-heads in reference to the term *kaaskop*. Is this considered a racial slur if you were to travel in the Netherlands? Just so I know not to use it if it is?

What would a person from the Netherlands response be to this? A punch in the face or a laugh? I'm not calling anyone a *Duitse* or even worse a *Belg*, that would be just plain rude. I just want to know for prosperities sake.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that cheddar is a foreign cheese in the Netherlands, since it originated in England.

Comment: Propriety's sake, perhaps?

Comment: posterity's sake I believe

Comment: @phoog *Kaas* is any cheese, not specifically cheddar.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I know that, but the asker's father seems either to have been unaware of it or to have disregarded it.

Comment: @KateGregory it is unclear why this question would be particularly relevant to future generations, but it is certainly about manners and/or correctness.

Answer (score 5):

In reference to a person, yes, it is a pejorative. From the [Dutch Wikipedia page on the term 'kaaskop'](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaaskop):

> In overdrachtelijke zin wordt het woord gebruikt voor een rond menselijk hoofd en bij uitbreiding als een pejoratieve term voor een domkop, vooral door Belgen en Zuid-Limburgers als een spotnaam (locofaulisme) voor de Hollanders. Ook in Duitsland, zeker in de westelijke streken, is Käskopp gebruikelijk als spotnaam voor Nederlanders

(Roughly) translated by me:

> In a metaphorical sense, the word is used for a round human head. By extension, it is a pejorative term for a dunce, especially used by Belgians and those from the south of Limburg as a mock name (locofaulism) for those from Holland. In Germany too, especially in the west of Germany, *Käskopp* is a common mock name for the Dutch.

Note that the Wikipedia page also describes a non-pejorative use. A *kaaskop* is the term for a mold in which Edammer cheese is traditionally made.

---

Apparently it can also be a reference to the 80-year war in which those Edammer molds (or other buckets used in cheese making) were used as improvised helmets. From [the Racial Slur Database](http://www.rsdb.org/slur/kaaskop):

> Dutch for "Cheese head". Refers to improvised helmets made of cheesbuckets, as worn by millitant farmers during the 80-year war.

While that database doesn't provide any references, I found one on my own. This is [(thematic) learning material for elementary school kids](https://8october.nl/media/1566217651lesbriefKinderontbijtAlkmaarOntzetantwoorden.pdf) on [the Siege of Alkmaar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Alkmaar), it contains the following passage:

> Als helm droegen de Alkmaarders emmers op hun hoofd, waarin ze kaas maakten. Daar hebben ze
> nu nog steeds hun bijnaam “kaaskoppen” aan te danken.

(Roughly) translated by me:

> People from the city of Alkmaar would wear buckets used for making cheese as improvised helmets. Because of that, they still have the nickname 'kaaskoppen' (cheese heads).

Comment: It may be used negative, many times the Dutch use it to describe themselves. Bend it into a possitive. (And I would not call it a racial, but national, slur, if you want to call it a slur.)

Comment: @Will yeah, it's like people from Kentucky calling themselves hillbillies and tourists from New York calling the locals hillbillies.

Comment: @Willeke yea, or even a regional slur. I don't think there's a lot of cheese-making in the Netherlands but outside of Holland (or at least not famously so) and I don't think the term is normally used by foreigners. As such, I can see it used by Dutch people from the provinces to refer to someone from Holland or by people from Holland amongst themselves. I've never heard it in the provinces when there's no connection to Holland, I guess we have other regional pejoratives here. ;p

Comment: @JJJ Well,half of the Groene Hart lies in the province of Utrecht and there is a long tradition of cheese making there,say in and around Woerden. But I guess that's close enough to be approximated by Holland.

Comment: It sounds like it's the equivalent of calling the French "Frogs" or the English "Rosbifs". A mild insult which might be made or taken jokingly, but might not.